# Checking email addresses with InternetAddress.validate()

Tags: java, email-validation

Why does the following code think that "hurt123@aol-com" is OK?

```
    public boolean validateEmail(String email) {
    boolean isValid = false;
    try {
        // Create InternetAddress object and validated the supplied
        // address which is this case is an email address.
        InternetAddress internetAddress = new InternetAddress(email, true); // strict
        internetAddress.validate();
        isValid = true;
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        System.out.println("Bad eMail address: " + email);
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: According to RFC 822 it is valid and that's what `validate()` is checking against.

Comment: Never saw such a domain name. What does it translate to? I mean, are there really sites with that designation? Guess that shows how times have changed.

Comment: It's interesting to note that the aforementioned address IS REJECTED by javax.mail.Authenticator() in Session. Go figure!

Answer (score 4):

`isValid = true` because `hurt123@aol-com` is a valid email address.

Although ICANN "highly discourages dotless email addresses", it is still a valid email address.
The format of email addresses is local-part@domain where the local part may be up to 64 octets long and the domain may have a maximum of 255 octets ([REF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1))

As long as the `local-part` and the `domain` are valid, it is a valid email address.

domain may be an IP address literal, surrounded by square brackets `[]`, such as `jsmith@[192.168.2.1]` or `jsmith@[IPv6:2001:db8::1]`

For example: `user1@localhost` is a valid email address.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. Unfortunately this makes InternetAddress.validate() nearly useless since 99.999% of the actual email addresses do have ".whatever" at the end and 100% occasionally make typos :-)